# How can I backup everything in Postgres 8, including indexes?

Tags: postgresql, backup

When I make a backup in postgres 8 it only backs up the schemas and data, but not the indexes. How can i do this?

Comment: How exactly are you currently creating your backups and exactly what version of Postgres are you using?  Generally pg_dump should also back up your indexes.

Comment: I'm using the GUI administrator for the backups, where I right click on the database and select "backup" with postgres 8.1

Comment: It looks like some subtle issue (as @Mike wrote indexes are included in pg_dump's backup, moreover there is no switch like `--omit-indexes`), so we need much more/full details (OS, minor version of PostgreSQL, pgAdmin version, backup format: COMPRESS, TAR, PLAIN) and some reproducible DDL if possible.

Comment: It is a Centos virtual server and postgres 8.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're making a backup using the pg_dump utility.  That saves the information needed to recreate the database from scratch.  You don't need to dump the information in the indexes for that to work.  You have the schema, and the schema includes the index definitions.  If you load this backup, the indexes will be rebuilt from the data, the same way they were created in the first place:  built as new rows are added.

If you want to do a physical backup of the database blocks on disk, which will include the indexes, you need to do a [PITR backup](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/continuous-archiving.html) instead.  That's a much more complicated procedure, but the resulting backup will be instantly usable.  The pg_dump style backups can take quite some time to restore.

Comment: Note, it may be useful to include the indexes in the dump (not just their definitions) in order to speed up the restore. If you have a data warehousing app with tons of indexes, the restore can take orders of magnitude longer because it has to regenerate all the indexes.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want a dump of the indexes as well as the original table data.

pg_dump will output CREATE INDEX statements at the end of the dump, which will recreate the indexes in the new database.

You can do a PITR backup as suggested by Greg Smith, or stop the database and just copy the binaries.

Comment: Right; I forgot to mention that if you can take the server down, you can make a full backup of the database just by copying the entire directory tree the database is in.  You need to be careful with symbolic links, which will be there if you created your own tablespaces--as well as in some other cases I won't get into all the details of.